# Where is this function argument coming from?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux

In the below code, I can't figure out where the `{getFirebase}` argument is coming from that is being passed in to the line that reads...

```
return (dispatch, getState, {getFirebase}) => {
```

*If you can't determine where it's coming from in the code below that I will post for context, please just state that in your answer along with any other helpful insights then I will accept your answer and ask another question with more code for context.*

Here is more code for context.

authActions.js

```
export const signIn = (credentials) => {
  return (dispatch, getState, {getFirebase}) => { // <- this is the line in question
    const firebase = getFirebase();

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      credentials.email,
      credentials.password
    ).then(() => {
      dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS' });
    }).catch((err) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_ERROR', err });
    });

  }
}

export const signOut = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState, {getFirebase}) => {
    const firebase = getFirebase();

    firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
      dispatch({ type: 'SIGNOUT_SUCCESS' })
    });
  }
}

export const signUp = (newUser) => {
  return (dispatch, getState, {getFirebase, getFirestore}) => {
    const firebase = getFirebase();
    const firestore = getFirestore();

    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      newUser.email, 
      newUser.password
    ).then(resp => {
      return firestore.collection('users').doc(resp.user.uid).set({
        firstName: newUser.firstName,
        lastName: newUser.lastName,
        initials: newUser.firstName[0] + newUser.lastName[0]
      });
    }).then(() => {
      dispatch({ type: 'SIGNUP_SUCCESS' });
    }).catch((err) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'SIGNUP_ERROR', err});
    });
  }
}
```

SignIn.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { signIn } from '../../store/actions/authActions'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

class SignIn extends Component {
  state = {
    email: '',
    password: ''
  }
  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    })
  }
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.signIn(this.state)
  }
  render() {
    const { authError, auth } = this.props;
    if (auth.uid) return <Redirect to='/' /> 
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <form className="white" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <h5 className="grey-text text-darken-3">Sign In</h5>
          <div className="input-field">
            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id='email' onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </div>
          <div className="input-field">
            <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id='password' onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </div>
          <div className="input-field">
            <button className="btn pink lighten-1 z-depth-0">Login</button>
            <div className="center red-text">
              { authError ? <p>{authError}</p> : null }
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return{
    authError: state.auth.authError,
    auth: state.firebase.auth
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    signIn: (creds) => dispatch(signIn(creds))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SignIn)
```

Comment: What do you mean *"where it's coming from"*? In the code you've actually posted, those parameters *aren't* provided anywhere.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: "those parameters aren't provided anywhere." That's what I mean. And that's what's causing my confusion. The `signIn` function takes a single argument `credentials` but then immediately returns an anonymous arrow function that is passed three arguments. Where do those three arguments "come from" is my question. Normally they would come from the calling function. In other words, when the function is called, the parameters of the function call would then map to the arguments of the function. But that doesn't seem to be happening here. 

Comment: It's clearly happening *somewhere*, just not in what you've posted. It's a higher-order function, the returned function is probably being invoked by the dispatcher. I'd suggest you read up on the libraries used in the project, but you can't just post random code and demand an explanation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I acknowledge in the OP that the answer might not be contained in the code provided in the question. I'm looking for help where to look. You: "I'd suggest you read up on the libraries used in the project" ... That's what I need help doing. Which library documentation should I research. Normally, I would research the library of the closest function. Which is why I posted the code of SignIn.js. But it doesn't seem to answer my question. You mentioned HOC. Should I look for an HOC to be the culprit here? I really don't understand HOCs or their syntax very well at this point.

Comment: That's probably a good place to start your research, then. But if *"the answer might not be contained in the question"* it's not a good one for SO.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Problem is, I did not know if the answer was contained in the question or not *at the time I wrote the question*. Which is why I asked the question in the first place. Guidance on where to start looking is just as helpful as an outright answer when you're looking for help. And "The answer is unknowable." is an acceptable answer that will close out the question. Especially if I can gain some guidance as to what to do next. And talking it through with others like you is a thousand times more helpful than sitting on it all alone.

Comment: You don't need to write `{ signIn: (creds) => dispatch(signIn(creds)) }`, just `{ sigIn }` would do the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`redux-thunk` middleware](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) supports [defining an "extra argument"](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#injecting-a-custom-argument):

```
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument(api))
)

// later
function fetchUser(id) {
  return (dispatch, getState, api) => {
    // you can use api here
  }
}
```

So, check the store setup logic for the app or example you're working with, and what you'll see is that it's creating a customized version of the `thunk` middleware, with an object that looks like `{getFirebase, getFirestore}`.  That object is then being passed in to all the thunk functions in the app.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly the help I was seeking. +1

Answer (score 1):

For example the function `signUp`:

This returns an anonymous function that takes three parameters. The last parameter is an object. The anonymous function uses the values with the keys `getFirebase` and `getFirestore` of this object.

So the value for `getFirebase` has to be given by the caller of the anonymous function that is returned by `signUp`.

```
var f = signUp("John Doe");
f(x => ..., x => ..., {getFirebase: value1, getFirestore: value2})
```

Inside the anonymous function the variable `getFirebase` now has the value `value1` and the variable `getFirestore` now has the value `value2`. As you cab see from the code, `value1` and `value2` have to be functions.